# Searching a list for a method to delete

Tags: python, list

```
import csv

list = []
list.append(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
list.append(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

def deletepublication(d):
    dp = input("Please input name of publication to be deleted")
    for i in d:
        if i[3] == dp:
            d.remove(i)
            break

deletepublication(list)

for i in list:
    print(i)
```

This function is supposed to loop through each entry in a specific column in a 2D list, then delete the row in the list containing the input entered. But when I try it with a value I know is in there, nothing happens, it isn't deleted

Comment: Where is your [mcve] that helps us reproduce your issue?

Comment: Oh yeah, hang on, I'll edit that in

Comment: It's still not verifiable because we don't have access to `"DADSA RESIT CWK JULY 2018.csv"`?

Comment: give a sample of the csv file, it is still not verifiable

Comment: i think you need `i[3].strip() == str(dp)`

Comment: looking at the given code , problem could be only with "if i[3] == dp:" condition

Comment: OK I've resubmitted the code with a sample array. Still the same outcome. Again, sorry about this.

Comment: your current code work fine if in input `d` for example, did you try it yourself?

Comment: No, that's the problem. I tried both upper and lower case d to test and neither rows were deleted. Sorry for the lack of clarity again

Comment: Avoid calling named values the name of Python functions like `list`. It will bite you...

Comment: i try it now in ipython with python 3.7 an its work. But you use bad name for variable `list`

Comment: Yeah don't worry I know. It's just the sample I was using was all. I only did it to make it clearer

Comment: I'm using Pycharm with I think Python 3.6. But I doubt that would be a problem for such a simple function as this

Comment: WAIT, it's working now. Dunno what I did, but the code you gave me worked. Thank you very much all!